# Linux shell to rename a file if it exists

Tags: linux, shell

Hey I have the following code which checks if the file already exists in the location that it was originally in before it was removed.
This works and if it does not exist then it will be moved which also works, 
But My question is how can I get the shell script to ask the user to specify a new name to rename the file to and then store it under the new name if a file with the same name exists already.
The code for the rename should go underneath the echo in the first part of the `if`

```
#! /bin/sh
#restore the dustbin contents 

if [[ -f "$(grep $1 /root/TAM/store) " ]]; then
   echo "A File with the same name already exists please rename this file to store it"
else 
   mv /root/TAM/dustbin/$1 `grep $1 /root/TAM/store`
   cd /root/TAM
   rm store
   touch store
fi
```

EDIT

```
read -p "please enter a new name:  " newName
mv /root/TAM/dustbin/$1 /root/TAM/dustbin/$newName
cd /root/TAM
rm store
touch store
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prompt the user, try doing this :

```
read -p "New name >>> " name
echo "The file name is $name"
```

Comment: @<sputnick> i have this code `read -p "please enter a new name" newName` then `read $newName` and `mv /root/TAM/dustbin/$1 $newName` but this doen't work any idea why?

Comment: @<sputnick> can you look at my new edit above and give me any tips on how to move the file to the destination ``grep $1 /root/TAM/store``  as for the life of me I just cant think of how to do it I tried the mv like this `mv /root/TAM/dustbin/$newName` `grep $1 /root/TAM/store` but I am sure this didn't work

Comment: `mv /root/TAM/dustbin/$newName \`grep $1 /root/TAM/store\` ` Should work. Note the \` around the grep expression.

Comment: Your script seems broken. Better tell us in english what you are really trying to do, what is your goal & the context

Comment: Maybe I forgot the grave keys I will retry it

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10768/bash-script-to-send-to-recycle-bin-or-trash

Comment: @<sputnick> I have three scripts one for moving a file to a dustbin dir, one for clearing the dustbin dir and this one for restoring a file to its ORIGINAL location.  I just can't get it to work with renaming the file to be restored and then storing it at its original location with the new name.  Does that help?  p.s It wasn't grave quotes its still not working

Comment: Your script is not commentated and seems broken (by syntax and design), I don't want to waste time on this. Better use the script from my last link.